# Combine output of Netstat and PS - linux

Tags: linux, parsing, output, pid, netstat

I want to combine the output of the following commands:

-NETSTAT

```
    [root]# netstat -nltp
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32552 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
 151634/java
```

-PS

```
[root]# ps -eo pid,cmd | grep 151634
130485 grep --color=auto 151634
151634 java -classpath
```

I want to combine the following 2 commands and have the following OUTPUT (txt file):

```
PORT PID CMD
123  333 java/etc
234  444 java/etcetc
345  555 java/etcetcetc
```

I've made the following:

```
netstat -nltp | awk '{print $4}' | sed -e 's/.*://'
```

This prints the PORT from netstat -nltp output

```
for i in `netstat -nltp | awk {'print $7}' | awk -F '/' {'print $1'} | uniq` ; do ps -eo pid,cmd | grep $(echo $i | sed "s/^\(.\)/[\1]/g") ; done
```

This gets the PID from netstat -nltp command and after that it displays the PID and CMD from PS command (also it excludes displaying grep --color=auto results

Thank you very much!

LE: I've removed the output html to avoid confusion. It was just an example on how it should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, i've manage to make the script work with all the duplicate problems etc.
Below you can find the updated scripts in case anyone else needs.
Thank you! :)

```
netstat -ntlp | sed 1,2d > /tmp/output_netstat.txt

echo PORT$'\t'PID$'\t'NAME
for port in $(cat /tmp/output_netstat.txt | awk '{print $4 " " $7}' | sed -e 's/.*://' | awk '{print $1}' | uniq)
do
    pid=$(cat /tmp/output_netstat.txt | grep -w "$port" | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d ' ' -f 7 | cut -d '/' -f 1 | uniq )
    ps_name=$(cat /tmp/output_netstat.txt | awk '{print $4 " " $7}' | sed -e 's/.*://' | sed 's/\// /g' | awk '{print $3}')
    ps_name_outputed=$(ps -ef | grep "$pid" | grep "$ps_name" | grep -v grep |tr -s ' '| sed 's/^[^0-9]*//g' | head -1 | cut -f2- -d/)
    echo  "$port"" ""$pid"" ""$ps_name_outputed"
done

rm -rf /tmp/output_netstat.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much JUSHJUSH,

I've written here my response because it was too long for the comment response.

I've updated also the script with that FOR and it worked, but, it seems that the script doesn't obtain the right OUTPUT.

I will try to explain below

If i have the following netstat -nltp output

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32552         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      151634/java
tcp        0      0 10.77.66.33:8081       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      151634/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7070            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      151634/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      151634/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20100           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      151634/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20101           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      151634/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20102           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      151634/java`

and the CMD for PID=151634 is `java -classpath /opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./conf:/opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar:`

the script gives the following OUTPUT:
`PORT PID CMD
32552   151634  java -classpath /opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./conf:/opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar:
32552   151634  java -classpath /opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./conf:/opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar: 
32552   151634  java -classpath /opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./conf:/opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar: 
32552   151634  java -classpath /opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./conf:/opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar: 
32552   151634  java -classpath /opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./conf:/opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar: 
32552   151634  java -classpath /opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./conf:/opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar: 
32552   151634  java -classpath /opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./conf:/opt/application/nifi-1.6.0/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar:`

The OUTPUT should have been
`PORT PID CMD
32552 151634 CMD from above
8081 151634 CMD from above
7070 151634 CMD from above
9090 151634 CMD from above
20100 151634 CMD from above
20101 151634 CMD from above
20102 151634 CMD from above`

Or, another example:

If i have the following netstat -nltp output

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3030          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      88284/ruby
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3031          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      88284/ruby`

and the CMD for PID=88284 is `/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/sensu/bin/sensu-client -c /etc/sensu/config.json -d /etc/sensu/conf.d -e /etc/sensu/extensions -p /var/run/sensu/sensu-client.pid -l /var/log/sensu/sensu-client.log -L warn`

the script gives the following OUTPUT:
`PORT PID CMD
3030    88284   /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/sensu/bin/sensu-client -c /etc/sensu/config.json -d /etc/sensu/conf.d -e /etc/sensu/extensions -p /var/run/sensu/sensu-client.pid -l /var/log/sensu/sensu-client.log -L warn
3030    88284   /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/sensu/bin/sensu-client -c /etc/sensu/config.json -d /etc/sensu/conf.d -e /etc/sensu/extensions -p /var/run/sensu/sensu-client.pid -l /var/log/sensu/sensu-client.log -L warn`

The OUTPUT should have been
`PORT PID CMD
3030 88284 CMD from above
3031 88284 CMD from above`

Thank you very much for your help and patience!